# How do I scrape a full table using rvest that uses a button to show more records?

Tags: r, rvest

I have a table that I'm trying to scrape.  The table has 100 rows.  The first 10 rows load initially, and I'm guessing the button to "Show Full List" must have a Javascript response.

I am looking for help on how to scrape the full table.

Here is the code I used to get the first 10 rows using `rvest`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'rvest'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:readr':
#> 
#>     guess_encoding
url <- "https://www.mlb.com/prospects"

html <- read_html(url)

html %>% 
  html_node("table") %>% 
  html_table()
#> # A tibble: 10 x 10
#>     Rank Player  Position Team   Level   eta   Age `Height / Weigh~ Bats  Throws
#>    <int> <chr>   <chr>    <chr>  <chr> <int> <int> <chr>            <chr> <chr> 
#>  1     1 Wander~ SS       Tampa~ -      2021    20 "5' 10\" / 189 ~ S     R     
#>  2     2 Adley ~ C        Balti~ -      2021    23 "6' 2\" / 220 l~ S     R     
#>  3     3 Spence~ 3B/1B    Detro~ -      2022    21 "6' 1\" / 220 l~ R     R     
#>  4     4 Jarred~ OF       Seatt~ AA     2021    21 "6' 1\" / 190 l~ L     L     
#>  5     5 Julio ~ OF       Seatt~ -      2022    20 "6' 3\" / 180 l~ R     R     
#>  6     6 MacKen~ LHP      San D~ ROK    2021    22 "6' 2\" / 197 l~ L     L     
#>  7     7 Bobby ~ SS       Kansa~ -      2022    20 "6' 1\" / 200 l~ R     R     
#>  8     8 CJ Abr~ SS       San D~ -      2022    20 "6' 2\" / 185 l~ L     R     
#>  9     9 Ke'Bry~ 3B       Pitts~ MLB    2021    24 "5' 10\" / 205 ~ R     R     
#> 10    10 Nate P~ RHP      Toron~ MLB    2021    24 "6' 6\" / 250 l~ R     R
```

Comment: why  don't you use the `RSelenium` answer below?

Comment: I have had issues getting `RSelenium` configured on my laptop without admin privileges

Comment: I believe the solution will probably involve phantom js, you'll find several sources if you lookup phantomjs and rvest together in your favorite search engine. Here's one : http://www.probabledistributions.com/2019/06/using-phantomjs-and-rvest-to-scrape-javascript-rendered-content-in-r/. I've never looked into it personally, so looking forward to the solution, RSelenium is a pain sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

Below a possible solution.

You could use RSelenium to interact with the page.

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
driver <- rsDriver(browser=c("firefox"), port = 4441L)
remote_driver <- driver[["client"]]
remote_driver$navigate("https://www.mlb.com/prospects")
remote_driver$findElement(using = 'css selector', value = '.load-more__button')$clickElement()
url<-unlist(remote_driver$getPageSource())

html <- read_html(url) 
    html %>% 
      html_node(css =".rankings__table") 
          %>% html_table()

        Rank                  Player Position                  Team Level  eta Age  Height / Weight Bats Throws
    1      1           Wander Franco       SS        Tampa Bay Rays     - 2021  20 5' 10" / 189 lbs    S      R
    2      2         Adley Rutschman        C     Baltimore Orioles     - 2021  23  6' 2" / 220 lbs    S      R
............
    98    98           Tyler Freeman       SS     Cleveland Indians     - 2022  21  6' 0" / 165 lbs    R      R
    99    99            Cade Cavalli      RHP  Washington Nationals   ROK 2022  22  6' 4" / 230 lbs    R      R
    100  100         Taylor Trammell       OF      Seattle Mariners   MLB 2021  23  6' 2" / 213 lbs    L
```